# Email Form Field Variable

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to take two form fields and check to see if the user had inputted anything into those two fields. If the fields have been filled in I want to email the value of those fields that the user entered. If the fields are empty or filled with only spaces I want to display a generic text message indicating in the email that states these form fields are empty. I tried empty(), isset() and many different variations of each as well as checking if a variable equals NULL and all do nothing. I am wondering what I am doing wrong and it has to be rather simply.

**HTML**

```
<div class="formField">Desired UserName: <input type="text" name="userName" style="width:200px;" value="" /></div>
<div class="formField">Desired Password: <input type="text" name="userPass" style="width:200px;" value="" /></div>
```

**PHP**

```
$userName = $_REQUEST['userName'];
$userPass = $_REQUEST['userPass'];

if ($userName === NULL ) {
    $userName = "Use Generic Username, No Preference Entered";
}

if ($userPass === NULL ) {
    $userPass = "Use Generic Password, No Preference Entered";
}

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Desired Username: ".$_POST["userName"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Desired Password: ".$_POST["userPass"]."\r\n";
```

Comment: Don't bother checking against `null`. Provided request parameters are *set* (eg `isset($_REQUEST['userName']`), they will never be `null`

Comment: Use `if (isset($_REQUEST['username']))` instead of assigning to a variable first.

Answer (score 1):

`$userName` and `$userPass` are not equal to null, When the user doesn't pass data it is just an empty string.

You can trim before checking:

```
$userName = isset($_REQUEST['userName'])? trim($_REQUEST['userName']): false;
```

[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) remove extra white spaces.

Now you can use it in your condition like so:

```
if (!$userName) { // if no username
    $userName = "Use Generic Username, No Preference Entered";
}
```

Comment: This did not work but I think if I can play around with this it will teach me something very useful regarding the isset() function. The guy's response below actually solved the problem. Thank you so much for your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you want something like this

```
$userName = !empty($_POST['userName']) ? $_POST['userName'] :
    'Use Generic Username, No Preference Entered';
$userPass = !empty($_POST['userPass']) ? $_POST['userPass'] :
    'Use Generic Password, No Preference Entered';

$MESSAGE_BODY .= sprintf('Desired Username: %s%sDesired Password: %s%s',
    $userName, PHP_EOL, $userPass, PHP_EOL);
```

Your main problem appears to be that you weren't using `$userName` and `$userPass` in your `$MESSAGE_BODY` string.

Comment: Your solution did work flawlessly. So let me see if I understand what is going on tho.

By stating
$userName = $_REQUEST['userName'];
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Desired Username: ".$_POST["userName"]."\r\n";

Does This actually mean I am rendering this line Useless?
$userName = $_REQUEST['userName'];

Comment: @MikeDinder yup. You were assigning values to `$userName` and `$userPass` then doing nothing with them. The values in `$_REQUEST` and `$_POST` remained unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userName = $_REQUEST['userName'];
$userPass = $_REQUEST['userPass'];

if (empty(trim($userName))) {
    $userName = "Use Generic Username, No Preference Entered";
}

if (empty(trim($userPass))) {
    $userPass = "Use Generic Password, No Preference Entered";
}

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Desired Username: ".$_POST["userName"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Desired Password: ".$_POST["userPass"]."\r\n";
```